# If a Gaussian measure has density, then its covariance is nondegenerate

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian-integral, gaussian-measure

A Gaussian measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is said to be Gaussian if its Fourier transform has the form:
$$\hat{\mu}(y) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}e^{i\langle y,x\rangle}d\mu(x) = e^{i\langle a,y\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\langle Ky,y\rangle}$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $K$ is a nonnegative symmetric matrix. I want to prove that if $\mu$ is Gaussian, then $\mu$ has density if, and only if $K$ is nondegenerate. I already proved that if $K$ is nondegenerate, then $\mu$ has density, but I'm stuck at the converse: if $\mu$ has density, then $K$ needs to be nondegenerate. Any hints, please?

Comment: I doubt that the statement as it stands is correct. Also for degenerate $K$ the measure will have a density. The support however will be only on a subspace of lower dimension.

Comment: @Tobsn But there will be no density function defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Yeah, sure. That's not contradicting what I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) tells us that the Fourier transform of an $L^{1}$ function vanishes at infinity.
But if $K$ is not positive definite there is some $y$ for which $\left\langle K y, y\right\rangle\le 0$.
So $\mathcal{F}\mu$ will not be heading to zero in that direction.

Comment: Ali, thanks so much. I still do not understand how does the existence of the density is implied by your answer. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @MathMath You said, "I already proved that if $K$ is nondegenerate, then $\mu$ has density"

Comment: Oh, sure. I got confused. Sorry